# Await async functions to be done in reduce() function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise, reduce, npm-request

I have a fuction which includes the following:

```
const newThreads = newItems.reduce( (acc, item) => {
  request(item.href, function(error2, response2, html2){

    if(!error2) {

      const thread = cheerio.load(html2)
      const today = thread('div#ignmsgbttns1').parent().parent().find("b:contains('Today')")

      if(today.text()) {
        acc.push(item)
      }

    }
  })
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(newThreads)
```

Of course the log returns an empty array, because of the async stuff 
(`request`)  executed in the `reduce` loop.

So what I would like to do is:

```
const newThreads = await newItems.reduce( etc...
```

And wait for the `requests` in the `reduce` loop to be done.

But I don't get my head around how to do it properly.

So I know I have to use `async`, `await` or `promises`, but don't know how to do it.

I think the `reduce callback` also has to be `async` but absolutely not sure on this point.

The `request` method comes from the [npm request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) , they also provide some [packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait) to use promises, but to be honest, I don't know how to apply it with `reduce`.

I'm pretty sure there is already a similar question somewhere but couldn't find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ps: for those wondering what cheerio is, here the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio).

**Final code after applying answer**

I had to use the [async-request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-request)

```
const newThreads = newItems.reduce(async (acc, item) => {
  const current = await acc;

  const html2 = await requestAsync(item.href);
  const thread = cheerio.load(html2.body);

  const today = thread('div#ignmsgbttns1')
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .find("b:contains('Today')");

  if (today.text()) current.push(item);

  return current;
}, []);

newThreads.then((res) => {  
  //..doing stuff with res 
})
```

Comment: It's really unclear why you want to use `reduce`. Shouldn't you build your result with `map` and possibly `filter`? Then you can trivially use `Promise.all`.

Comment: @Bergi As far as I know `map` returns an array with equal length as the original, in my case I have to filter out some items. But you're right, maybe I will give `filter` a try even if my issue is solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work you'll need the [Promise returning version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait).

```
const newThreads = newItems.reduce(async (acc, item) => { // note async
  const current = await acc; // unwrap the previous Promise
  try {
    const html2 = await request(item.href); // unwrap request Promise
    const thread = cheerio.load(html2);
    const today = thread('div#ignmsgbttns1')
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .find("b:contains('Today')");

    if (today.text()) current.push(item);
  } catch (error2) {
    // do whatever
  }
  return current;
}, []);
```

The `newThreads` variable will be a Promise of an array of items that passed the conditional check.

Comment: Thx for your answer. with your method html2 now returns a request object, but should return a string containing the requested html. Also when logging newThreads I get "Promise { <pending> }". Do I have to use one of these request-promise packages?

Comment: @OlivierKrull You cannot immediately return the result string from an asynchronous function. Just wait for the promise.

Comment: Had to make some adaptations to your code, but basically this is the right answer thx